# Changing a jenkins slave DNS entry

Tags: ssh, jenkins, amazon-ec2, dns, slave

I recently changed the DNS cname record of one of the slaves that my jenkins machine uses. After the change was made, I updated the information in the node so that it points to the new name. Since then, the jenkins slave fails to launch with the following error:

```
[09/10/14 18:24:11] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to name.domain.com:22.
ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for ubuntu (credentialId:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/method:publickey)
[09/10/14 18:24:11] [SSH] Authentication failed.
hudson.AbortException: Authentication failed.
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:1143)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:648)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:642)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[09/10/14 18:24:11] [SSH] Connection closed.
[09/10/14 18:24:11] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
```

Can anyone give me info on how I might resolve this? Its using the same key that had been working prior to the DNS change.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is visible on the line that says:

```
ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for ubuntu (credentialId:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/method:publickey)
```

You need to log into the slave and examine /var/log/auth.log to discover why the slave refused the key.

You might want to double-check which credential the slave is configured to use. Sometimes when I have edited slave configuration, some settings have changed that I have no recollection changing.

Comment: Thank you, I'm very new to this. I found this error in the log, but can't find info about how to resolve it.

sshd[3568]: Received disconnect from xx.x.x.x: 11: Closed due to user request. [preauth]

Comment: If the slave connection worked before slave DNS change, maybe there is something in Jenkins that has associated the slave DNS name with the ssh hostkey. Unfortunately I do not know where that might be. I suggest you make a new slave (e.g. by cloning it) and remove the original.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an odd issue that has to do with AWS permissions, and to be honest I don't entirely understand the why of it, but in the end I was able to resolve the issue.

The machine would not accept the .pem key that I had previously been using. I ended up having to make a new pem key and add it to authorized keys on the destination machine.

I confirmed that I am still able to use the original key to ssh into the box, but for some reason it would not work from the jenkins machine.